# jQuery Validation Plugin - Form does not submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, submit

I'm using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org), and I have a problem.
Both my `jQuery` and `HTML` is perfectly valid (according to `JSLint` and the `WC3 Markup Validation Service`), but when I hit the submit button, nothing happens.
My code even clearly states that, upon submitting, an alert should pop up, but even that doesn't work. The form is however validated correctly, and in the and, all fields are green  (meaning they passed validation) but it doesn't actually submit (nothing happens).
Also, in my `DevTools`, the console does not report any errors.

---

*Possibly/probably relevant;* the email-textfield and the username-textfield are both being checked by a remote `PHP` script. This script works, strange enough, **only** after the second time. So when I first leave (`blur`) the email-textfield, nothing happens, it's isn't marked correct nor false.
 Only when I (re-enter and) leave the textfield for the second time, it is validated, or when I hit the submit button. *(This shows the submit button is actually connected, it just simply does not submit)*

I really hope someone will solve my problem. I'm not trying to just let someone else do the work. I validated, checked, debugged, but nothing solved my problem.

---

My `HTML` (it's in a modal using Bootstrap):

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="signupModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
<form class="form-horizontal" id="signupform" method="post" action="/" role="form">
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <p class="lead">For creating an account,</p>
                  <p class="lead text-right">you'll have to give us some information.</p>


                    <div id="emailgroup" class="form-group">
                        <label for="signupemail">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your Emailaddress</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>&nbsp;</span>
                                <input type="email" name="signupemail" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="on" required class="form-control" id="signupemail"   placeholder="Email">

                            </div>
                            <label class="control-label error-label" for="signupemail"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="fnamegroup" class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputfname">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your Full Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;</span>
                                <input type="text" name="fname" required class="form-control" id="inputfname" placeholder="Barack Obama">
                            </div>
                            <label class="control-label error-label" for="inputfname"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="unamegroup" class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputuname">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your Username</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">&nbsp;@&nbsp;</span>
                                <input type="text" name="uname" required class="form-control" id="inputuname" placeholder="PresidentofAmerica">
                            </div>
                            <label class="control-label error-label" for="inputuname"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div id="thepasswordgroup" class="form-group">
                        <label for="thepassword">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your Password</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>&nbsp;</span>
                                <input type="password" name="thepassword" required class="form-control" id="thepassword" placeholder="123456789" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                            <label class="control-label error-label" for="thepassword"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div><br />

                     <div id="gendergroup">
                        <label>Your Gender</label>                       
                            <div class="radio">
                             <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="radio" name="gendergroup" id="gendergroupmale" value="male" checked>I'm a Male</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                             <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="radio" name="gendergroup" id="gendergroupfemale" value="female">I'm a Female</label>
                            </div>                       
                    </div>
                   <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="taccheckbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Terms and Conditions</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <input id="taccheckbox" name="taccheckbox" type="checkbox" required>
                                        </span>

                                <input style="cursor:default !important;" type="text" id="something" value="I accept the Terms and Conditions" readonly class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <label class="control-label error-label" for="taccheckbox"></label>
                            <!-- /input-group -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    </div>



            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <p>
                        Have already got an account? <strong><a href="#" onClick="$('#signupModal').modal('hide'); $('#loginModal').delay(1500).modal('show');">Login here!</a></strong></p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" id="signupsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign Up">
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

My `Javascript`/`jQuery`:

```js
$('#signupform').validate({
        rules: {
            signupemail: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "/functions/verifysignup.php",
                    type: "post"
                }
            },
            fname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                maxlength: 30
            },
            uname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 20,
                remote: {
                    url: "/functions/verifysignup.php",
                    type: "post"
                }               
            },
            thepassword: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 20
            },
            taccheckbox: "required"
        },

        messages: {
            email: {
                remote: "This emailaddress is already in use"
            },
            taccheckbox: {
                required: "You have to accept the Terms and Conditions"
            },
            fname: {
                minlength: "At least 8 characters required",
                maxlength: "Max. 30 characters"
            },
            uname: {
                minlength: "At least 6 characters required",
                maxlength: "Max. 20 characters",
                remote: "This username is already in use"
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('called');
            $('#signupsubmitbtn').prop("disabled", false);
            //^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{6,15}$ username        
            form.submit();
        },

        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.attr('id') == "taccheckbox") {
                error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().next());
            } else {
                error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
            }
        },

        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            $('#signupsubmitbtn').prop("disabled", true);
        },

        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').find('label.control-label label').text('');
            if ($('.has-error').length === 0) {
                $('#signupsubmitbtn').prop("disabled", false);
            }
        },

        success: function (element) {
            element.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            if ($('.has-error').length === 0) {
                $('#signupsubmitbtn').prop("disabled", false);
            }
            //element.parent().next().text('');

        }
    });
```

My remote `PHP` script:

```php
<?php
define ('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require('connect.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST['signupemail'])){
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['signupemail']);
    $thearray = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE email=\"".$email."\""));

    if($thearray[0] > 0){
        echo '"This emailaddress is already in use"';
    } else {
        echo "True";
    }

} else if(isset($_REQUEST['uname'])){
    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['uname']);
    $thearray = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE uname=\"".$uname."\"")); 
    $forbiddennames = array(1 => 'super-user','superuser', 'root', 'admin', 'administrator', 'system', 'website', 'site', 'owner', 'manager', 'founder','moderator');    

    if(in_array(strtolower($_REQUEST['uname']), $forbiddennames)) {
        echo '"'.$_REQUEST['uname'].' is a forbidden username"';
    } else if($thearray[0] > 0){
        echo '"This username is already in use, please choose another"';
    } else {
        echo "True";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks very close to correct to me.  One issue is that you have your php script echoing `True` back, but it has to be `true` (lower case).  That actually matters.

Otherwise, IMO your script looks fine.

The stuff you're saying about it not calling your submitHandler, or only triggering the remote bits doesn't really seem to be the case to me.  I copied your code and simply added a bit of debugging (i.e. to console.log when remote gets triggered or when submitHandler gets called) and both got called at the appropriate times.

For instance, if you type a valid email and then click to the next field, it immediately validates the email address.

So whatever issues you're having, are not related to the code you've shown (except for that one error with `true` vs `True`).

Here's a working example of your code, for reference:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/tWH9M/1/

In order to test it with remote working teh way you have it setup, you have to find this bit:

```
    signupemail: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: {
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                json: function () {
                    return 'true';
                }
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                $('#log').append('remote signupemail triggered<br>');
            },
            type: 'post'
        },
    },
```

And change that `return 'true';` to `return 'True';`

Comment: Sorry, and in case it's not clear, I have to use a different data and url due to how jsfiddle works.  the json:function stuff just tells it what I want returned via AJAX (in this case - `true`)

Comment: Wow, the `True`issue was the problem! Never thought it would something be so simple. On the other hand, the documentation for `remote` wasn't very clear, so it's difficult to know what the rules are. Anyway, thank you!